# combining LIKE with IN operator in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to do some thing like this:

```
select * from table1 where name Like in (select name from table2 where id = '%123')
```

Suppose

```
select name from table2 where id = '%123'
```

Results are: `abc123,def123,ghi123,...`

And the `table1` contains the name fields as `AB-abc123-CD,CD-def123-HB,...`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```
select * from table1 where name in (select name from table2 where id Like '%123')
```

OR

```
select * from table1 inner join table2 on table1.name like '%' || table2.name || '%'
where table2.id = '%123'
```

Did I understand you question correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This works on SQL Server, I assume it will work on MySQL too, possibly with minor modifications.

```
select distinct t1.* from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
on t1.name like '%' + t2.name + '%'
where t2.ShortString like '%123'
```